# How to take a numerical number and store in variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to take or extract the numerical digit number and store in variable. For example i have var data=18:00, so i want to take 18 and store in variable and similarly take 00 and store in another variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SOUGAT, you can try [split](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/String/split.html) method.

```
var data = '18:00'
List<String> dataList = data.split(':');
print(dataList[0]); //18
print(dataList[1]);//00
```

Comment: I have another doubt that for example if have a Text widget which has a text data 18:00 that is Text('18:00'); and then i extract or get this data and stored in a variable that is var data=Text('18:00'); print(data); .But problem is after printing "data" i am getting an output "Text("18:00")" instead of 18:00

Comment: @SOUGAT, that's because you're storing Text widget along with numerical data. You will need to extract only the text and assign it to data. Make sure you have `TextEditingController` assigned to your `Text` widget and then extract it as `var data = textEditingController.text`.